# defining a variable using ls and awk

Tags: awk

all.

I'm using tcsh (I know, it's not good). Anyway, I'm defining a variable as

```
set arqlink = `ls -aFl /usr/lib64/libelf* | awk '/->/{print $NF}' |
grep "libelf-0"`
```

but it doesn't work and I don't know why since

```
ls -aFl /usr/lib64/libelf* | awk '/->/{print $NF}' | grep "libelf-0"
```

works just fine.

thanks in advance.

best regards,

nc

Comment: I forgot to add that, if I use any other library name, instead of libelf, defining the variable that way works fine:

Comment: I assume you meant `tcsh` instead of `tsch` and and changed your Q to reflect that. To have clearly legible code that shows all of  your syntax elements, (note how the back-tics are now visible) use 4 spaces at the front of each line of code/data/error msgs OR highlight a block of text and use the `{}` format tool at the top left of the edit box to format as code/data/output. Good luck.

Comment: You are probably getting `set: No match.`. Try using `set arglink = \`stat -c %N /usr/lib64/libelf* | awk '/->/{print $NF}' | grep "libelf-0"\` `.

Comment: Since you only tagged awk: remove that `grep` and use `... | awk '/->/ && /libelf-0/ {print $NF}'` or `awk '/->/ && $NF ~ /libelf-0/ {print $NF}'`.

Comment: If I were doing something that I knew was "not good" and it was causing me problems, I'd like to think I'd stop doing that and instead do something that "is good". Maybe that's just me....

Answer (score 1):

By default `tcsh` has `nonomatch` unset.

> ```
>    nonomatch
>      If set, a Filename substitution or Directory stack substitution (q.v.) which
>      does not match any existing files is left untouched rather than
>      causing an error.
> ```

Set this on and your line will work.

```
set nonomatch
set arqlink = `ls -aFl /usr/lib64/libelf* | awk '/->/{print $NF}' | grep "libelf-0"`
```

Alternatively, use `stat` and you won't need to set `nonomatch`.

```
set arglink = `stat -c %N /usr/lib64/libelf* | awk '/->/{print $NF}' | grep "libelf-0"`
```

Bottom line is, `-F` is forcing `ls` to append `*` to the filenames which is considered `no match`. You can also alter your original command and get rid of `-F`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove spaces on both sides of `=` and note the `backtick` (not single quote) added on both sides of command.

```
set arqlink=`ls -aFl /usr/lib64/libelf* | awk '/->/{print $NF}' |
  grep "libelf-0"`
```

Comment: O.P. had backticks in place, but were obscured by not using proper formatting tool. AND `set var = val` is the correct syntax for `[t]csh`. You wouldn't use the word `set` in a variable assignment in `bash`.

Comment: thanks for the promptly reply, sheelter and JRG but it still doesn't work.